# Calculating minimum weight matchings in graphs with self-loops

Tags: algorithms, matching-theory

> **Question:**
>
> which of the minimum-weight perfect matching algorithms can properly deal with the presence of self-loops?

The motivation for the question is the calculation of minimum-weight 'imperfect' matchings in the presence of negative edge-weights.

That can be accomplished by duplicating the graph and connect each vertex to its image via an edge of length 0.

If a matching algorithm could correctly handle self-loops, then connecting each vertex with itself by a self-loop of length 0 would considerably speed up the calculation.

The algorithms should however also handle self-loops of non-zero length correctly.